# converting strings from a map to a 2d vector character-wise

Tags: c++, vector, maps, stringstream

I have an array of strings which need to be taken into a map. Since the array size is variable, I need a 2d vector to obtain the string character-wise. i need both formats of storage for operations i perform on them. Here's my attemp..gives errors in (EDIT:)run time.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

#define rep(i,a,b) for(int i=(a);i<=(b);i++)

using namespace std;
std::map<int,string>col;
std::map<int,string>row;
std::map<int,string>::iterator p;     
std::map<int,string>d1; 
std::map<int,string>d2;

int main()
{   
    int i=0,r=0;
    string s;

    ifstream ip; 
    ip.open("a.in"); 

    ofstream op; 
    op.open("a_out.in");

    ip>>s;

    const int c= s.length();
    ip.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

    do { 
        ip>>s;row.insert(make_pair(r,s));
        r++;
    }while(s.length()==c);

    p=row.find(--r);
    row.erase(p);
    p = row.begin();

    while(p!=row.end())
    {
        cout<<(p->first)<<","<<(p->second)<<"\n";
        p++;
    }

    vector<vector<char>>matrix(r,vector<char>(c)); 

    rep(i,0,r){
        int k=0;rep(j,0,c)(p->second).copy(&matrix[i][j],1,k++);
    }

    rep(i,0,r)
        rep(j,0,c)
            cout<<matrix[i][j];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: If it's giving you errors, post the errors.

Comment: I am very sorry for the confusion..i meant run time..must be out of my mind while typing..here's the error anyways
Expression:map/set iterator not dereferencable

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it meets your needs!

Comment: Also I recommend you compile this with maximum warnings (e.g. `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` in GCC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem occurs after you print out the map, before you copy the strings into the vector. You need two things:

```
while(p!=row.end())
{
    cout<<(p->first)<<","<<(p->second)<<"\n";
    p++;
}
p = row.begin();   // Must reset iterator!

vector<vector<char>>matrix(r,vector<char>(c));
rep(i,0,r){
    int k=0;
    rep(j,0,c)(p->second).copy(&matrix[i][j],1,k++);
    ++p; // Must advance the iterator.
}
```

That should fix the map/set iterator not dereferencable, as in the doubly nested for loop you referenced an invalid iterator (p was set to row.end()).

Edit:
Also, unless you can assume that all the strings are the same length, you might consider a different technique. When you use `const int c = s.length()`, you are telling the `map<int,string>` and `vector<char>` the length of EVERY string in your file are the exact same length. If the second string is shorter than the first, you will try to access characters in the string that don't exist! Note the

```
rep(j,0,c) (p->second).copy(&matrix[i][j],1,k++)
```

will fail since it thinks it has `c` characters, when it in fact will not.

Comment: thanks! its workin..i figured out the missing p++ later on but reset iterator was what i missed out. :)

Comment: i got that handled ..i know all strings upto a certain point have same length as the first

Comment: @Aseem If this answer solved your problem, click on the checkbox near the answer to select it as the official answer to this question.